# a question about second-order log-linear approximation

Tags: log-linearization

I have a very simple question. [image]

I don't understand OA6 equation. Where is the 2, the denominator of $\frac{v_{11}}{2}$, gone?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the partial derivative of (OA5) wrt $y_i$ to zero, the division by 2 can be simplified, and disappears:
$$ \frac{ \partial v}{\partial y_i}(y_i,y, a_i,\omega)=0 \iff v_1 + v_{11}y_i+v_{12}y+v_{13}a_i+v_{14}\omega = 0. $$
When you solve this equation in $y_i$, you will find the optimal level  $y_i^*$, almost as given in (OA6), but the constant term $v_1$ is actually missing there.

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand! By the way could you give me more details? So how does the division by2 disappear?

Comment: @user14261785: I have added the first order condition for an inner maximum.

Comment: I just saw your edited answer. Thanks!